# Alias defined in .ps1 not recognized in .bat

Tags: powershell, alias

I'm launching a a setup.ps1 defining a bunch of aliases
later on I'm calling a .bat file using those aliases and I get the "is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

Am I forgetting something completely obvious as to why this doesn't work ? Or shouldn't it work and I'm out of my mind.

Here's a made up example,

setup.ps1

```bsh
New-Alias vs "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

content of example.bat

```
vs newfile.txt
```

open a powershell

> . .\setup.ps1
>
> example.bat

Comment: PowerShell aliases aren't visible outside PowerShell. You'd have to define DosKey macros inside your batch file to get equivalent functionality.